# p:selectOneMenu keyboard navigation to select values doesn't select the next option with same starting letter

Tags: primefaces, html-select

If we look at the primefaces showcase for [selectOneMenu](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml), select the Editable dropdown and now try to type 'b' it selects "Barcelona", if I type the letter 'b' again it should have selected "Berlin"; but looks like it doesn't. The selectoOneMenu rendered page shows me  but somehow this doesn't work.

If we look at the HTML select in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amoram/b2b740uk/1/) when I type 's' consecutively it toggles between 'Saab' and 'Subaru'. Is this a bug or do I need to do something to enable it?

```
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="subaru">Subaru</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: Does it only fail for the editable one? Tried the others to? Please file an issue in the PrimeFaces github

Comment: I am seeing it happening for all drop downs in my project, it doesn't go to the next option too, let me file an issue.

Comment: Looks like someone already opened a issue [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2356)

Comment: Ok, so next time you'll search the issuelist first ;-)

Comment: :) yes, I was about to file an issue but searched first and voila found one already. But they marked it as a "new feature" instead of an issue, I am not sure if their terminology of "new feature" is different.

Comment: Before posting a question I mean... ;-)

Comment: yes, in future before posting here to :)

Comment: Great!... hope it gets fixed or maybe you can check if you can create a patch yourself. The source **is** open amd fairly clearly written

Comment: March 2019 and it is still a bug. I had to revert to standard html dropdown because it was unacceptable by our QA guys. My case was with US list of states, typing M should navigate from Maine, Maryland, and so on to Montana and then back to Maine. shame on you Primefaces.